# Checkbox is marked then it will provide a dollar amount in another field

Tags: javascript

I am creating a vehichle condition report which is for a detailing company.  At the bottom there are checkbox fields with the detailing packages.  At the end of each description is a field for the dollar amount.  What I am trying to do is if the checkbox is checked it will then place the correct dollar amount in that field which is at the end.

Example

> (CB1) Silver Package   `_____` < this field would show $65.00
>   (CB2) Gold Package  `________` < this field would show $85.00

I know how to calculate the total but I have not been able to say if this box is checked then this filed will show the dollar amount due.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think its really simple. please check this

```
 <body>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 <!--
    function assignvalue(x, id, value)
    {
        if(x.checked)
            document.getElementById(id).value = "$" + value;
        else
            document.getElementById(id).value = "$";
    }
 //-->
 </script>
  <input type="checkbox" onclick="assignvalue(this, 'SilPack', '65.00')"><input type = "text" id = "SilPack">
  <input type="checkbox" onclick="assignvalue(this, 'GoldPack','85.00')"><input type = "text" id = "GoldPack">
 </body>
```

checkbox have checked attribute which can be checked and then assign appropriate values to corresponding textbox